# Yii2: Kartik Gridview: How to hide the expand/collapse icon column/use only clickable row instead

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, kartik-v

Using Kartik Gridview, I have the following ExpandRowColumn in my view (Kartik Gridview) where I have enabled the rows in the grid to be clicked and expanded (to show related detail record) with the enableRowClick option and would like to hide the entire expand/collapse icon row and use only the row click ability.  I have tried setting the 'disabled' option but that just makes the ExpandRowColumn disabled altogether.

```
[
  'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
  'width' => '50px',
  'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
       return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
   },
   'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
       return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_example', ['model' => $model]);
   },
   'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
   'expandOneOnly' => true,
   'enableRowClick' => true,
],
```

Comment: Hmm... Not sure if that's possible without modifying widget itself... :|

Answer (score 1):

I hacked the widget source, have managed to make the icons go away but the column remains. Plus of course it should come back with I update the widget :-) !

in \vendor\kartik-v\yii2-grid\ExpandRowColumn.php

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    if (empty($this->detail) && empty($this->detailUrl)) {
        throw new InvalidConfigException("Either the 'detail' or 'detailUrl' must be entered");
    }
    $this->format = 'raw';
//    $this->expandIcon = $this->getIcon('expand');
//    $this->collapseIcon = $this->getIcon('collapse');
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I need a more long-term solution that makes the column disappear though your proposed solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'width' => '50px',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_expand', ['model' => $model]);
            },
            'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
            'expandOneOnly' => true,
            'expandIcon' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>',
            'collapseIcon' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>',
        ],
```

Comment: Why not try expanding on your answer rather than just posting code!! Elaborate more on why this answer will benefit the OP!

Comment: I don't think this will make the actual row disappear will it?  I'm not using Yii2 too much these days and don't have a quick way to test, but I think your code is just making the icon disappear correct?  My original question was how to make the actual icon ROW disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue. At last, I just succeeded by placing empty string.   My workaround will be as follows

```
[
  'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
  'width' => '50px',
  'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
      return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
   },
  'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
      return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_expand', ['model' => $model]);
   },
  'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
  'expandOneOnly' => true,
  'expandIcon' => '',
  'collapseIcon' => '',
],
```